# Filter Excel Based On Date

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I want to use Blueprism to filter a dataset based on a particular date.
The I column  want to filter is a date time column.

When I pass a value of 01/05/2020 * no values are returned.
There are values such as 01/05/2020 03:17:42

Code:

```
GetInstance(handle).Range(range). _ 
AutoFilter(Field:=Field,Criteria1:=SearchInput)
```

Comment: 1) make sure that the cells in Excel are of actual date type and not string 2) try greater >= 01/05/2020 and <= 01/05/2020 - although if formatted as datetime a straight = should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `01/05/2020 03:17:42` is not the same as `01/05/2020` it is bigger. Dates are saved as numeric values (amount of days since `1900-01-01`).

For example `2020-05-01  03:17:42` is the numeric value `43951.13729` where `43951` is the amount of days since `1900-01-01` and `0.13729` is the part of a day (the time)

So if you have dates including times you need to a filter that includes all dates `>=2020-05-01` and `<2020-05-02`. In Excel filters on dates should use the numeric values you can convert the date in `SearchInput` using `CDbl()`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think the code would accept a >= value

Comment: @E_McAndrew It does because a real date is not considered a string (as it looks like) but a numeric value of type `Double`.